# C# Linq - Extract members of list within dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, generic-collections

I have a use case for a dictionary like this one

```
var foo = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
```

so this collection will hold some hierarchical data like this

- Key 1

  - Value 1
  - Value 2
- Key 2

  - Value 3

and I need to get\project a list of values ignoring the keys, so result would be

- Value 1
- Value 2
- Value 3

on the first attempt I came up with this

```
IReadOnlyList<string> bar = foo.Select(r => r.Value.Select(x => x.ToString()))
                             .Select(r => r.ToString())
                             .ToList();
```

Is this any good?

Comment: with or without duplicates?

Comment: with duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SelectMany`:

```
foo.SelectMany(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that Dictionary already provides an O(1) way to access its list of values (same as you can access its list of keys) via its Values property

> The order of the values in the
>   Dictionary.ValueCollection is unspecified, but it is the
>   same order as the associated keys in the
>   Dictionary.KeyCollection returned by the Keys property.
>
> The returned Dictionary.ValueCollection is not a static
>   copy; instead, the Dictionary.ValueCollection refers
>   back to the values in the original Dictionary.
>   Therefore, changes to the Dictionary continue to be
>   reflected in the Dictionary.ValueCollection.
>
> Getting the value of this property is an O(1) operation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Right! So iterating on George's and Marcin's answers it could be more appropriate to this

foo.Values.SelectMany(x => x).ToList()

Comment: Have you seen the Pets example at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx - probably Marcin's suggestion is the more efficient one since they also use that one